# Who wrote the Microsoft case study about Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, microsoft

I just happened to notice [this case study](https://www.microsoft.com/danmark/cases/Microsoft-Visual-Studio-2008/Stack-Overflow/Developers-See-Faster-Web-Coding-Better-Performance-with-Model-View-Controller/4000006676) ([archived](http://web.archive.org/web/20160318230216/https://www.microsoft.com/danmark/cases/Microsoft-Visual-Studio-2008/Stack-Overflow/Developers-See-Faster-Web-Coding-Better-Performance-with-Model-View-Controller/4000006676)), published two years ago. It explains how Stack Overflow is using [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) to gain high performance, fast development and easier testing and code maintenance.

All good and very dandy, but who wrote this? I couldn't find any reference for author.

Has the author personally interviewed [Jeff Atwood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Atwood) and [Joel Spolsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky), or used information available online?

Last, but not least, is there any way to update the information on that page?

Comment: I think this is a question for Microsoft, not Meta Stack Overflow...

Comment: Said Yahoo... lol....

Comment: @Yeah but it's related to Stack Overflow as well. Know it's in the gray zone, but trying my luck. :-)

Comment: [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com) of Microsoft (and all-around good guy :) [is checking into this.](https://twitter.com/#!/shanselman/status/198250832683208704)

Comment: @JarrodDixon huge thanks, looks like you just called the cavalry! If Scott will be successful in his little investigation he surely deserve to get bumped over 1K rep at last. :-)

Comment: @Jarrod any updates? I will take "No, the information is not available" as an answer too. :)

Comment: @kenorb thanks for fixing the link!