# How does deletion affect previous unawarded bounties?

Tags: discussion, bounties, deleted-questions, expired-bounty

I see [When a question that had bounties is deleted, are they automatically refunded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145329/when-a-question-that-had-bounties-is-deleted-are-they-automatically-refunded) is very similar, but this is discussing bounties that expired and were awarded and may have been refunded by a moderator, not bounties that were never awarded and deleted by the OP.

Similarly, this is not a duplicate of [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) because there is no mention of the behavior of question deletion and how it affects **unawarded** bounties which is the key part of this question.  The behavior when it comes to awarded bounties and deletion is clearly spelled out but is not relevant to this question.

---

Several months ago, I put a 200 rep bounty on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234875/opera-on-android-stole-the-diamonds-from-mobile-site (10K only), but the bounty was never awarded (the question was not my own question, but one for a similar issue I had experienced).

Today, the OP apparently deleted the question on his own, and the unawarded bounty was refunded to me.  I want to ask why, especially when the bounty was so long ago.

I paid for the attention (although the problem still exists), so why should I get my "fee" back just because it was deleted?  The reason I ask is this would appear to be a loophole to allow users who post a bounty and don't get an answer to recover their rep (by getting the question deleted).

My question is ultimately is:

- Why is a bounty, which is considered a "fee" for advertising, refunded automatically without manually being refunded (as is suggested by the question I linked) when the question is deleted.
- What would have happened if this was my own question that had an unawarded bounty (presumably with no answers) and I deleted it myself.  Would it have still refunded my rep?
- What will happen if the question is undeleted?  Would the refunded 200 rep bounty be un-refunded?

The reason I ask is this would seem to be a loophole that would permit a user to ask a question, post a bounty and if they don't get an answer, allow them to recover the rep via deletion, then undelete or reask the same question, post a new bounty (and repeat until they get an answer).

Comment: If you remove your own question which you bountied previously, you get the rep from the bounty back. If you undelete it, you lose this rep from bounties again. A user can't recover rep via deleting because if he undelete, he loses all the rep recovered via deletion.

Comment: @nicael now that you say that, I seem to remember one of your experiments.  I am going to guess that this is a dup of that if you actually asked a question and haven't deleted it.  Is it still there to close as a duplicate of?

Comment: No, I haven't asked *this* question, because it didn't seem to me to be bug.

Comment: I think you should just tag this [bug]. This doesn't make any sense as behavior. Someone could delete a question with a failed bounty and reask the question as a new post and place the same bounty again, cc @nicael

Comment: @rene not sure the new edit to the faq addresses the case of unawrded bounties. I saw tge deatured post ss well, and it seems both are talking about awardsd bounties. Am I missing something?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I would expect that the just implemented feature would also  cover this case but maybe I was struck by premature hammering. Let me re-open and raise some attention to this post to see if or how this is now covered.

Comment: @rene Subquestions 2 and 3 are covered in the FAQ, but 1 isn't. I think this should be edited to address 1 exclusively, so it's not a dupe of any question.

Comment: @Ano why does the FAQ cover 2 and 3.  Everything in the FAQ and the feature post talk about questions with awarded bounties that get deleted.  It says nothing about unawarded.

Comment: @psubsee2003 It was clear in the previous text, but became unclear after I updated that text with the recent changes...I made it clear again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog care to point to the section in the FAQ that answers my question?

Comment: Agree it's not a dupe, if it gets closed ping me and I'll reopen.

Comment: @Sha Thanks.  I can reopen it too, but I'll let you do it so there isn't someone complaining about a "conflict of interest" if it gets closed

Comment: Huh, right, you also have discussion hammer. Cheers!

Comment: While your question isn't answered in the FAQ I linked, it is, however, answered in [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that), which states that *all* reputation changes from bounties are nullified (except in the specific case where the awarded answer got to keep its bounty because it had a score of 3 and was visible for at least 60 days, which is not applicable here). (cc @ShadowWizard)

Comment: @Sonic still, think it's fine to have it as separate question or at least not sure enough to use my hammer to close.